# Hudson fingerprints show use in other jobs but not relationship between projects

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I can't get tests to aggregate.  I believe this is because hudson refuses to make a "project relationship" between my upstream and downstream jobs.  I have fingerprints enabled; and viewing the fingerprint report for my build artifact shows the other jobs.  However, on the "project relationships" page the up & down jobs are "no records" linking the jobs.

Related question:  [Problems with "Aggregate downstream test results" in Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387164/problems-with-aggregate-downstream-test-results-in-hudson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to aggregate test results the fingerprinted artifact **must** be *introduced* by Hudson.  I assume this is determined by both:

- The timestamp on the file being newer than the time the build started
- The MD5 checksum must have never been generated before.

If a file is used and fingerprinted by Hudson out of SCM it can never be "introduced" by Hudson even if it is generated by a Hudson job (and happens to be identical).

Edit:
Also...  you **can't** publish JUnit test results for a job and also aggregate with downstream projects.  Only the results of the upstream project will be shown if JUnit is enabled on it.